# Lambda multiple functions implementation in Python like Linux Pipeline command

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am implementing this requirement:

> As part of a data processing pipeline, complete the implementation of the pipeline method:
>
> - The method should accept a variable number of functions, and it
>   should return a new function that accepts one parameter *arg*.
> - The returned function should call the first function in the pipeline
>   with the parameter *arg*, and call the second function with the result
>   of the first function.
> - The returned function should continue calling each function in the
>   pipeline in order, following the same pattern, and return the value
>   from the last function.
>
> For example, `pipeline(lambda x: x * 3, lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x / 2)` then calling the returned function with 3 should return 5.0.

## My code

```
def pipeline(*funcs):
    def helper(arg):
        argCount = len(funcs)
        if argCount > 0:
            # Iterate over all the arguments and call each lamba's function
            res = []
            for elem in funcs:
                if(len(res) > 0):
                    helper = elem(res.pop())
                else:
                    helper = elem(arg)
                res.append(helper)
            helper = res.pop()
        else:   
            return helper
            
        print('before returning, helper value is: ', helper)
    return helper
    
fun = pipeline(lambda x: x * 3, lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x / 2)
print('final result: ', fun(3)) #should print 5.0
```

## Question

`None` is returned. Why?

```
before returning, helper value is:  5.0  
final result:  None
```

Comment: I did the python 3 code implementation and I reached to final result as 5.0, but with return helper then it will only return None

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't execute a `return` right after you `print`. You *do* have a `return` in the `else` branch just before it, but not in the `if` block. Also, the `return helper` you have further below does not belong to the `def helper` function block, so you need one more `return helper`. I would in fact omit the `else` block, and just always do the return, like this:

```
def pipeline(*funcs):
    def helper(arg):
        argCount = len(funcs)
        if argCount > 0:
            # Iterate over all the arguments and call each lamba's function
            res = []
            for elem in funcs:
                if(len(res) > 0):
                    helper = elem(res.pop())
                else:
                    helper = elem(arg)
                res.append(helper)
            helper = res.pop()
        print('before returning, helper value is: ', helper)
        return helper # <-------

    return helper
```

It is not really clear why you have a list `res`, since there is only one value to pass from one function to the next. You could just use `arg` for this purpose. Furthermore, you use `helper` in two different senses (function & value) which is quite confusing. The code can be simplified to this:

```
def pipeline(*funcs):
    def helper(arg):
        for elem in funcs:
            arg = elem(arg)
        return arg

    return helper
```

Comment: Great Trincot. I used your code and worked perfectly. Much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Do not invent what is already available in Python

```
from functools import reduce

pipeline = [lambda x: x * 3, lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x / 2]

val = reduce(lambda x, f: f(x), pipeline, 3)

print(val)  # 5.0
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from functools import reduce`?

Comment: The original code came from an Interview coding question - level Hard for Python exam and I am just at beginner level, I am aware of reduce API. I am not trying to re-invent!

Comment: lol consider those test makers have failed level easy for Python

Answer (score 1):

You do: `print('before returning, helper value is: ', helper)`... *and then do not actually return anything from `helper`*, so it implicitly returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def pipeline(*args):
    def helper(num):
        for i in args:
            total=i(num)
            num=total
        return total
    return helper

fun = pipeline(lambda x: x * 3, lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x / 2)
print(fun(3)) #should print 5.0
```